# TFS Build Server cannot get publish profile to work: "Can't find the valid AspnetCompilerPath"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

I have a Solution with a bunch of Web Projects and i want my build server to automatically create packages for each project.
I am able to to get (nearly) everything working.
The builds are fine and the packages will be created on each build.
But only when i do not specify a PublishProfile in the MSBuild Arguments.
So it will only insert default values and not precompile my Web Sites and such.
(Arguments are `/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:IsAutoBuild=True /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0`)

However I want to use the publish profiles (.pubxml) i created in Visual Studio.
Each Project has a "Test.pubxml".
But when i specify the PublishProfile parameter, the build will fail with the following error message (Arguments are `/p:DeployOnBuild=True;PublishProfile=Test /p:IsAutoBuild=True /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0`):

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets (411): Can't find the valid AspnetCompilerPath`

Yes, the file `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets` does exist in that folder.
I can deploy the projects from Visual Studio on my developer machine just fine.

I am using the following:
Windows Server 2012 R2
Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 1 (Installed on build server)
Projects are for .Net 4.5.1

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, found this question, and came up with a slightly less hacky solution:

Just add `/P:Framework40Dir=c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319` as an additional MSBuild parameter.

No need to edit .targets files or set anything else.  Worked for me, so I just do:

```
msbuild MyWebProject.csproj /T:Package /P:PublishProfile=MyProfile /P:Framework40Dir=(as above)
```

I use it to build a Web Deploy package into a subfolder of my choosing - without the profile, it goes to `obj/debug/package`.  Who uses `obj`?  Blergh :)

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error and got around it with a bit of a hack.

I edited the **Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets** file.

Find the **AspnetCompilerPath** node in and replace **$(Framework40Dir)** with **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319**.

I suppose you could set the value of $(Framework40Dir) earlier in the file.

I recommend creating a backup of the file before changing it (the file also has a comment at the top suggesting this).

I guessing that the proper solution would be to set some environment variable or registry value.

Comment: This works! (Apparently $(Framework40Dir) was set to the msbuild directory rather than the .NET framework).