# TFS Build Server "Can't find the valid AspnetCompilerPath" for TeamBuild publishing a Website

Tags: tfs, msbuild, vs-web-site-project, publish-profiles

I am having a problem with TFS2013 using a Team Build which does a build then a publish of a website.
Everything works fine when I do a Publish Web site from my dev machine using VS2013 and the (right-click) Publish Web site 
option for the Web site project.  I get the following error on the TFS2013 Build server:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets(421,5): error :

```
**Can't find the valid AspnetCompilerPath** [C:\Builds\3\Web\Development to WebDev\Sources\Web\Website\Development\ASP.NET\App\website.publishproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Builds\3\Web\Development to WebDev\Sources\Web\Website\Development\ASP.NET\App\website.publishproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

**

I am using the follow MSBuild arguments in the Team Build setup.
*/p:DeployOnBuild=true;VisualStudioVersion=12.0;DeployTarget=WebFileSystemPublish;PublishProfile=Development*

The Development Web Transform works fine on the Build Server in response to the 'PublishProfile=Development' argument. The 
Web.Config file is properly transformed for our Development environment.
As noted in the MSBuild Argument, I use the FileSystem publish option and want to keep it that way.

I have modified the Build Server 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets'
to log some properties as follows in Target 'ConfigureForAspNetPreCompileMerge':

```
<Message Text="[TargetFrameworkVersion]: $(TargetFrameworkVersion)" />
<Message Text="[AspnetCompilerPath]: $(AspnetCompilerPath)" />
<Message Text="[Framework40Dir]: $(Framework40Dir)" />
<Message Text="[MSBuildToolsRoot]: $(MSBuildToolsRoot)" />
<Message Text="[MSBuildRuntimeVersion]: $(MSBuildRuntimeVersion)" />
```

Which logs the following information to the website.log file for the Team Build:
ConfigureForAspNetPreCompileMerge:

> [TargetFrameworkVersion]: v4.0 
>   [AspnetCompilerPath]:
>   [Framework40Dir]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\v4.0.30319
>   [MSBuildToolsRoot]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\
>   [MSBuildRuntimeVersion]: 4.0.30319

The [Framework40Dir] is different than my local machine logging the same data at the same MSBuild target:

> 12>    Task Parameter:Text=[TargetFrameworkVersion]: v4.0 12>
>   [TargetFrameworkVersion]: v4.0 12>    Task
>   Parameter:Text=[AspnetCompilerPath]:  12>    [AspnetCompilerPath]: 
>   12>    Task Parameter:Text=[Framework40Dir]:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 12>    [Framework40Dir]:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 12>    Task
>   Parameter:Text=[MSBuildToolsRoot]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ 12>
>   [MSBuildToolsRoot]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ 12>    Task
>   Parameter:Text=[MSBuildFrameworkToolsRoot]:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ 12>
>   [MSBuildFrameworkToolsRoot]: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ 12>
>   Task Parameter:Text=[MSBuildRuntimeVersion]: 4.0.30319 12>
>   [MSBuildRuntimeVersion]: 4.0.30319

The TeamBuild value for [Framework40Dir] is: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\v4.0.30319' vs
my local DEV machine of: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

This seems very unusual.

I have also changed the TeamBuild file: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets'
to manually set the property of Framework40Dir as 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319'
but that seems to hang the whole TeamBuild process when it gets to that point and runs the Team Build forever until I manually stop it.

This is the same solution that worked here: [TFS Build Server cannot get publish profile to work: "Can't find the valid AspnetCompilerPath"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341102/tfs-build-server-cannot-get-publish-profile-to-work-cant-find-the-valid-aspne)
but it doesn't work for me.  That issue is identical to my problem.

The Build server is up to date with TFS2013.3.  I do not have Visual Studio 2013 installed on that machine and would very much like 
not to do that.  I have read that VS is not needed for TFS Team Builds.

Help with this issue is very much appreciated.....Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would install vs2013 onto the build server it removes the majority of these issues, allows you to run code coverage against your unit tests and doesn't require a licence as long as you have a valid licence on your development machine. I know this isn't the answer you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That is my next option unless something else pops up.

Comment: same result after installing VS2013 with Update 3 on the TFS2013 Build Server.   [Framework40Dir]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\v4.0.30319  is set to the MSBuild directory location in the TeamBuild target of 'ConfigureForAspNetPreCompileMerge'.

Comment: Have you logged onto the build server and built it in vs on there?

Comment: Within VS2013 on the TFS2013 Build Server, the solution was built and published successfully....exactly like my dev machine.  And again, the Team Build failed with the following error:               
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets(423,5): error : Can't find the valid AspnetCompilerPath

Comment: Which template are you using?

Comment: Humour me and remove the visual studio argument, in fact how far does it get with no arguments? What are the configuration and platform settings on the build definition.

Comment: I removed all MSBuild arguments passed in for the TeamBuild setup and the website publish did not attempt any ASPnet compile or merge.  The Configuration to Build is 'Any CPU|Debug'.

Comment: I'll be honest I'm really struggling, you would have thought that [Framework40Dir] issue would have been fixed once vs was installed and the fact that it builds in VS on the build server would have enforced this. I run minimal arguments on my web builds and only pass in /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Development, all the additional information required should be available in the PublishProfile. I'll try and trace the [Framework40Dir] today if i get time but I'm stuck for time and ideas at the moment sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the secret sauce.  I needed to set the ToolsVersion in my website.publishproj file Project section to "12.0".

I also needed to set the ToolsVersion to "12.0" in the DefaultTemplate.xaml 'Run MSBuild for Project' workflow activities as detailed in this article.

[Building Visual Studio 2013 solutions with your TFS 2010 / 2012 Build Templates](http://hamidshahid.blogspot.com/2013/10/building-visual-studio-2013-solutions.html)

The TeamBuild now works like the VS2013 Publish Web site....but this whole process takes almost twice as long as the former Web Deployment Projects we used before.  I will have to investigate if there is some way to speed up the Publish process.

Hope this helps someone else with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

please change the $(Framework40Dir) with this path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319.

Comment: or add /p:Framework40Dir="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" to the msbuild command line.